# c++ enable_if for non-type template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, enable-if, non-type

I'm a bit confused about partial template specialization... I have some code that depends on an arithmetic data type T, and on a small integer DIM. I want to be able to specify different class methods for different values of DIM. The impossibility of using partial template specialization led me to explore enable_if. It's exactly what I needed... except I want it to return a number and not a type. How can I do that? The following code should illustrate what I want.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, int DIM>
class foo{
    public:
        T function();

};


template <typename T, int DIM>
T foo<T, std::enable_if<DIM == 1>::value>::function(){
    // do something
    return 1.0;
}

template <typename T, int DIM>
T foo<T, std::enable_if<DIM == 2>::value>::function(){  
    // do something else
    return 2342.0;
}

int main(){
    foo<int, 1> object;
    int ak = object.function();
    std::cout << ak << "\n";

    return 0;   
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can totally do what you want with `enable_if`, just remember, the substitution has to fail when the condition is false, so you must call `type` to ensure the substitution fails when specializing for various conditions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, int DIM>
class foo
{
public:
    template <int D = DIM>
    typename std::enable_if<D == 1, T>::type
    function()
    {
        // do something
        return 1.0;
    }

    template <int D = DIM>
    typename std::enable_if<D == 2, T>::type
    function()
    {
        // do something else
        return 2342.0;
    }

};

int main(){
    foo<int, 1> object;
    int ak = object.function();
    std::cout << ak << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

For simple scenarios, like the one above (where you check a specific value, rather than a range of values), you can also use partial specialization. But if you would like to specialize, say, for all values from `1-50`, another for `51-200`, and then a generic fallthrough, `enable_if` works great.

You can also use `enable_if` in the template signature. Just a quick example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, int DIM>
class foo
{
public:
    template <int D = DIM, typename std::enable_if<D == 1, void>::type* = nullptr>
    T function()
    {
        // do something
        return 1.0;
    }

    template <int D = DIM, typename std::enable_if<D == 2, void>::type* = nullptr>
    T function()
    {
        // do something else
        return 2342.0;
    }

};

int main(){
    foo<int, 1> object;
    int ak = object.function();
    std::cout << ak << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice but i think it's possible to make it a little simpler: isn't necessary mirror every template parameter (`U` and `D`) to activate SFINAE: it's enough a template parameter involved in the `std::enable_if` test. So should work simply as `template <int D = DIM, typename std::enable_if<D == 1>::type* = nullptr> T function()` (and `void` is the default returned type for `std::enable_if`

Comment: Or also `template <int D = DIM> typename std::enable_if<D == 1, T>::type function()`

Comment: @max66 I just made it explicit (I'm originally a Python programmer, so especially when explaining concepts, I like being explicit over implicit), but yes, both of those are completely valid suggestions and I would use your style for production code. Although removing `U = T` is actually a great overall suggestion. Edited.

Answer (score 5):

You can partial specialize the whole class:

```
template <typename T, int DIM>
class foo;

template <typename T>
class foo<T, 1>
{
public:
    T function() {
         // do something
         return 1.0;
     }
};

template <typename T>
class foo<T, 2>
{
public:
    T function() {
         // do something
         return 2342.0;
     }
};
```

If you have lot of common code between both specialization, you may still use inheritance (inherit from common part or just the specialized part).

An easy alternative way is to use Tag dispatching:

```
template <typename T, int dim>
class foo
{
public:
    T function();
};

 template <typename T>
 T function_helper(foo<T, 1>&) {
     // do something
     return 1.0;
 }

 template <typename T>
 T function_helper(foo<T, 2>&) {
     // do something
     return 2342.0;
 }

template <typename T, int dim>
T foo::function() {
    return function_helper(*this);
}
```

But in C++17, `if constexpr` allows simpler syntax:

```
template <typename T, int DIM>
class foo
{
public:
    T function() {
        if constexpr (DIM == 1) {
            // do something
            return 1.0;
        } else if constexpr (DIM == 2) {
            // do something
            return 2342.0;
        }
    } 
};
```

C++20 with contraints allows

```
template <typename T, int DIM>
class foo
{
public:
    T function() requires (DIM == 1) {
        // do something
        return 1.0;
    }
    T function() requires (DIM == 2) {
        // do something
        return 2342.0;
    } 
};
```

Comment: I chose the other answer because it solved my problem and yielded more explicit code, but this is very interesting! Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Use the std::integral_constant type to wrap your values, as in:

```
std::integral_constant<int, 2>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but may I ask why?